How to get an academic position when your post-doc supervisor gives you a terrible reference?
I am in conflict with my post-doc advisor. I am leaving the lab and trying to find new positions, but all my applications die when prospective advisors talk to my current post-doc advisor.
Since the beginning of my post-doc, the projects and collaborations that I have been working on were totally different than those described when I accepted the position. Further, my advisor learned that I had had an issue with a big-shot professor (they sexually harassed me) and immediately formed a collaboration with this person. Despite this, and despite receiving literally no mentorship or advise whatsoever, I have mentored multiple students successfully and  received some small awards.
Since this first award, my advisor announced that they will not be able to extend my contract. Since then, they have become extremely hostile and have even started to monitor my internet, and turning other post-docs against me, creating competition by telling them that I will steal their projects when I am gone. They also went out of their way to reject my application to a summer school, instead accepting students who applied after the deadline. Many of the summer school attendees would have been good supervisors for me, but she falsely told them that I falsified my CV.
Since then, I have applied many times to positions that seem promising, but as soon as the PI talks to my advisor, I am rejected. I did receive one offer, but I suspect my advisor falsely told them that there was probably some issue with my PhD degree, because my department secretary told me that they had called to confirm that I have been awarded a PhD. On another occasion, I tried to collaborate with some young PIs, but my advisor swooped in and began collaborating with one of them themselves, at which point my attempt to collaborate fell apart.
How do I move forward? It does not seem like I will able to get another position if my advisor keeps lying about me and undermining me.
My current strategy is to add links with proofs of whatever I mention on my CV, so that if my PI accuses me of falsifying my CV, she will get exposed of lying.

Frankly, if you believe that an agent of a university shared information about you that they were not entitled to share, and that has been damaging to your education and your career, you should be talking to a lawyer.

Your location is very important. In some countries, some of the actions described here are flat-out illegal.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

OK, I've attempted to move all the important clarifications from the comments into the main post. You may make further edits if I botched anything, but please try to control the length and readability; the previous version probably would have been closed eventually. Also, I agree with the others that you need to (1) state the part of the world you are in (as this could very well be a legal issue, in which case jurisdiction matters), and (2) be very clear about what you are sure about and can prove vs. what you are assuming or speculating.

Maybe you mentioned it and I didn’t pick up on it, but what was the outcome of sitting down and discussing the situation and your concerns with your advisor?

@Aruralreader When I discussed with her that she doesn't give opportunities to me like she gives to other students and postdocs, she mentioned my "personality". And when I asked what exactly in my personality bothers her she didn't answer. I usually try to deal with my issues internally, so up to that point I haven't discussed with her any issue I had with her, I have never complained or argued with her up to that point. However that discussion was intense because I pulled out or the instances of unfair treatment I could remember and compared it to other postdocs. She was refusing everything..

Q: How to get an academic position when...  A: Publish strong research.

@GEdgar Yes but how if your advisor blocks your way ? Also obviously I am leaving before publishing anything because my contract was for one year

How did your PI know who you collaborate with, when they swoop in?

Because when I apply for positions they contact my PI to ask why I am leaving so early. In that occasion the PI had an announcement on their webside advertising the position as part of a collaboration mentioning the names of the other PIs, and I assume she read it from the website, or even asked them on the phone, and then approached one of those PIs to collaborate with her instead of the other younger ones (& me). The PI she contacted had an ERC grant under review.
